# Session variable in joomla 2.5 external file

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, fix-my-code, session, jsession

I am trying to set a value in external file but the session values are not set correctly. The session is set some times and other times it is not set. I am setting a session using ajax call following is the code in external file.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('continent',123456); //Set session name and value
echo $session->get('continent'); //Get session value
```

In ajax call I can get the session values using "$session->get('continent')" but when I try to get the session value in inside Jommla I get null or nothing.

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('continent');
```

I just use the above code to get the value. Can some one tell me what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

Your App initialization is not exactly the same than Joomla! CMS. Any minor difference can cause a condition to create a new session, instead of the reusing the original session.

Instead of trying to load the session from an external file, you can just implement a controller task inside the CMS, to avoid any risk of not loading the same session.